# Issue in Calendar List Sp2013

Tags: sharepoint-2013, splist

Event in calendar list in sp2013 is showing one day off the date entered after creation of event. This text in blue (attachment) is calculated col[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dy0yk.png)umn "=[Leader Level]&"-"&[Investigator Location]&"-"&TEXT([Start Date],"mm/dd/yyyy")" but it is not taking start date as entered instead it is showing one day off that day.

Answer (score 0):

check your user profile settings. Right above the screen, click your name, about me. You can define your locale there which is used throughout the web application.

Check if your time and date settings are correct under 'Language and region'. Specify 'always use my personal settings'. If it helps, then your locale is wrong within the site settings.

Hope this helps